# What is the smallest $20$ digit number with at least $13$ distinct prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, prime-factorization

The number $10^{19}+1035830$ is a $20$-digit number with $12$ distinct prime factors. I am not sure whether it is the smallest example because to save time I only considered numbers with at least $3$ prime factors below $100$, so I might have overlooked a smaller example.

> What is the smallest $20$-digit number with at least $13$ prime factors ?

With brute force, I did not find an example yet. I consider the numbers having at least $5$ prime factors below $100$. Brute force does not seem to be a good way to find the desired number. Does anyone know a more efficient algorithm that guarantees to find the smallest example ?

Comment: $$10^{19}+255252260$$ has $13$ distinct prime factors. Is it the smallest example ?

Comment: By the way, $$10000000118047509570$$ has $14$ distinct prime factors. Is this the smallest example with $20$ digits ?

Comment: And finally, is $$10^{19}+104058800385530$$ the smallest $20$-digit number with $15$ distinct prime factors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got
$$10\,000\,000\,000\,255\,252\,260=2^2\cdot 3\cdot5\cdot 7\cdot13\cdot19\cdot37\cdot43\cdot61\cdot73\cdot101\cdot107\cdot1259$$
(with $10$ zeros after the initial  $1$!). This number was obtained by multiplying the primes up to $7$, resulting in $210$, and then factoring the multiples of $210$ larger than $10^{19}$ until one was found having $\geq13$ prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

At least one can find some upper bound, i.e., some integer $n\ge 10^{19}$, 
by multiplying $13$ different primes to an integer $m$, such that 
$m<10^{19}$, and then using the minimal factor to obtain a number $>10^{19}$. For example,
$$
m=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 19\cdot 23\cdot 29\cdot 31\cdot 37\cdot 43=319091739796830
$$
gives
$$
n=31339m=10000016033492855370,
$$
having again exactly $13$ different prime divisors. 
Varying the primes of $m$, one can have better bounds.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Your $m$ seems to have $13$ prime factors...shouldn't it only have $12$.  And (2) Is there a reason you used $43$ instead of $41$?

Comment: Yes, $43$ gives a better result than $41$. And also I want that $m$ has already $13$ prime divisors, to make sure, in case the minimal factor does *not* contain a new prime divisor.